# What is the impact of awaiting in an actor in fire-and-forget or character actor situations?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, akka.net

There's a lot of Akka .NET literature warning against the use of `await` from within an actor's message handling code. Waiting for a task to finish will prevent the actor from processing further messages until the task has completed.

Nonetheless, I wanted to check whether using `await` made sense under these specific circumstances. Before I delve into the scenarios, though, here is the recommended approach for asynchronous continuations (taken from the Petabridge Akka .NET Bootcamp, Unit 3 Lesson 4) to put things in context:

```
// asynchronously download the image and pipe the results to ourself
_httpClient.GetAsync(imageUrl).ContinueWith(httpRequest =>
{
    var response = httpRequest.Result;

    // successful img download
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var contentStream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        try
        {
            contentStream.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            return new ImageDownloadResult(image,
                response.StatusCode, contentStream.Result);
        }
        catch //timeout exceptions!
        {
            return new ImageDownloadResult(image, HttpStatusCode.PartialContent);
        }
    }

    return new ImageDownloadResult(image, response.StatusCode);
},
  TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously)
 .PipeTo(Self);
```

**1. Keep the same structure, but use async/await.**

The above example won't cause problems because `GetAsync()` isn't being awaited. It's effectively run in fire-and-forget fashion. So is there anything that prevents us from using `Task.Run()`, then inside it running all the code we need with async/await inside (and NOT awaiting `Task.Run()`)?

**2. Use the Character Actor Pattern.**

In the Character Actor pattern, you create a child and delegate any dangerous operations to it. An HTTP request is considered a dangerous operation as it's likely enough to fail. If we spawn a child actor per HTTP request (or possibly spawn a pool of child actors using one of the routing strategies that checks whether actors are busy before forwarding messages to them), does it really matter if we `await` from within its message handling code, given that it isn't designed to execute any other requests at the same time?